# Workflow time trigger Limitation

Tags: workflow, limits, time-dependent-workflow

I got the next message from SF :

> Hourly limit exceeded for processing workflow time triggers.

I read that the limitation for Enterprise Org is 1000 per hour. ( https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_limits.htm&type=5 )

When I entered to **/services/data/v45.0/limits** From the workbench I saw a very strange thing :

[image]

but when I went to Setup => Monitor => Time-Based Workflow, I saw 196 rows but none of them are Time-Dependent Workflow. Its Immediate Workflow.

So I don't really understand where it's coming from and why I see limit of 50 at  Workbench while 1000 in SF Limitation Docs...

What I didn't understand here correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow there was a mistake at SF and we got a limit of 50 on enterprise edition, but they fixed that quickly :)

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be the confusion is there : Everything you can see in  Setup => Monitor => Time-Based Workflow is in fact a Time-Based workflow. Immediate actions won't appear there.

Do you, by any chance, check the limit against a developer org? Developer has a limit of exactly 50 Hourly Time Based Workflows.
If you encounter this problem on Enterprise Org and it only processes 50 workflows / hour I recommend logging a case to SFDC, check this link : 
[SFDC Case for workflow action limit](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316268&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: Hi, Yes, a developer Org had the same Limitation.
BTW - On Setup => Monitor => Time-Based Workflow  I saw that every hour its take only 50.
I logged a case to SF but since it is pretty urgent, I raised the question here as well.
Thanks!